# cifs missing from Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, mount, samba, cifs

Attempting to mount a windows filesystem with `-t cifs` yields:

```
 mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
```

Sure enought:

```
lsmod | grep cifs
```

Shows nothing.  Doing `modprobe cifs` gives me:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.6-100.fc34.x86_64+debug
```

Doing `dnf install cifs-utils` says:

```
Package cifs-utils-6.13-3.fc34.x86_64 is already installed.
```

I even removed that package and reinstalled to no effect.
I must be doing something wrong, Fedora wouldn't remove cifs, would it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you’re missing the kernel modules package. Since you’re using the debug kernel, you should run

```
sudo dnf install kernel-debug-modules
```

You might want the regular kernel instead. To switch to that, make sure it is installed,

```
sudo dnf install kernel
```

then reboot into it, and remove the debug kernel (Fedora won’t let you remove the running kernel by default):

```
sudo dnf remove kernel-debug{,-core,-modules}
```